# Delete button in table, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the code, using JS and jQuery. The code adds new rows to my table. Every row contains the delete button and it do not work. I'm going to implement also edit button.

My table:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-striped" id = "my-table">
       <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Example</th>

        </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>



          </tbody>

        </table>

   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) {
dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
mm='0'+mm
} 
today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
//var counter = 1;


$('button#sending_button').click(function(){
    var text = $('textarea#mytextarea').val();
    $('#my-table').append('<tr><td>'+today+'</td><td>'+text+'</td><td><button type="button" id="delete-button"  class="btn btn-danger">Usuń</button></td></tr>');
    $('textarea#mytextarea').val('');
    //counter++;

});

$('#my-table').on('click', 'button.btn btn-danger', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();  

});
```

});

I don't know what more I should explain about this problem.

Comment: Note that you are duplicating the IDs of the delete button. That is not valid, and behaviour with dealing with non-unique ID is undefined across browsers.

Comment: Try to add the button on('click') event after appending the rows on the html

Comment: @KentAguilar the code already uses event delegation, doing so later would have no impact.

Comment: In addition to the wrong selector, you'll probably want `$(this).closest("tr").remove()`.  While `.parents()` may work in this case, if you have a nested table it will remove more than expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
$('#my-table').on('click', 'button.btn btn-danger', function() {
```

It should be `button.btn.btn-danger`.

Some random suggestions:

- Don't repeat the id of each button ("`delete-button`"): id's should be unique
- Use a semantically meaningful class instead (`delete button` would also be good)
- Use said class when defining the delegate event listener, instead of `button.btn.btn-danger` (which is too bound to the DOM and its style definition)
- Use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) instead of [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to avoid surprises. They're two different methods with different goals
- Event better, use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: I tried two times: '$('button.btn btn-danger').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('td').remove()});' and '$('button.btn btn-danger').on( "click", function( event ) {
    $( event.target ).closest( "tr" ).remove()});' Everyone do not work.

Comment: @MichaelZ.Please read *carefully* my answer: it's `button.btn.btn-danger`, with *no* spaces anywhere.

Comment: I did it with dots and the result is the same. It doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelZ. With the information you provided, [it *does* work](https://output.jsbin.com/ketavefaho). If there's something else you should report (console logs, error messages...), change your original post.